# p4 command line equivalent to “git log -p”?

Tags: git, command-line, diff, perforce

I often use `git log -p <file>` or `git log -p <directory>` to get a comprehensive summary of the changes in a file or set of files. It outputs a history of the commits affecting the files, together with a unified diff of each commit.

Using Perforce I can do `p4 changes <file>` or `p4 changes <directory>/...` to get a list of commits. But there does not seem to be an option to show the corresponding diffs.

**Is there a Perforce equivalent I could use?** If shell scripting is necessary, a fully working function would be nice.

If you want to know why I miss the feature, here are a few things that `git log -p` lets me do *extremely* quickly:

- what was the last `.cpp` file to be modified?
- find all commits where the string `FOO` has been added to a file.
- a function just got deprecated; what did other developers replace it with?
- in general, just know what happened recently in a given directory.

Comment: Is this because you want to build your own history-viewing tool? Why not use P4V's Time Lapse View? Wonderful tool! If you want to build your own tool, combining 'changes' with 'describe' should get you there. Learn to use 'tagged' mode for your commands, or investigate using one of the Perforce scripting APIs.

Comment: The time lapse view is a decent tool, but it’s GUI only. It also has very limited search features, and only supports one file at a time. I’ll add a few examples of what `git log -p` brings me in terms of usefulness.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a reasonable approximation:

```
p4log () {
  p4 changes "$1" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -i p4 describe -du {} | less -F
}
```

Note that unlike `git log -p`, an argument is mandatory. You can give a pattern like `p4log ...` to run it against everything under the current directory recursively.

**Details**

`p4 changes "$1"`: Get one-line change summaries (most recent to oldest) for files matched by the pattern.

`awk '{print $2}'`: Extract the change number.

`p4 describe -du CHANGE [$CHANGE2 etc]`: Output the complete change description and diffs. The -du specifies unified diff format, which is closest to git's diff format.

`xargs -i p4 describe -du {}`: Run the describe command with all the change numbers as its arguments.

`less -F`: Page if longer than one screen, dump to terminal otherwise. Git pipes most of its output through less -F by default