# How to get list of commit history using Perforce api?

Tags: java, perforce

I'm using perforce api for java to get the commit history of a perforce repo.

I browsed through the complete set of functions available for the Iserver interface.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/IServer.html

Can someone please point me out what functions can I look for? OR 
Is there is any simpler and better way to handle this?

What I want is -

1) Who made the last few (say 5) commits in a branch.

Answer (score 2):

To find out who made the last 5 commits in a branch, try Server.getChangelists():

[http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/IServer.html#getChangelists(int, java.util.List, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/IServer.html#getChangelists(int,%20java.util.List,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean))

Specify maxMostRecent=5, and for your fileSpecs, specify //depot/branch/name/...

Since you only want committed changes, specify submittedOnly=true.

I think you can disregard the other arguments to getChangelists for your particular use case.

Once you have retrieved those changelists, look at the getUsername function in the ChangelistSummary that you get back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `p4 filelog`

Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503860/p4-command-line-equivalent-to-git-log-p) is a post of stackoverflow for a custom function.

Comment: Can I use this with perforce api? Isnt this the command line function?

Comment: @ajc perforce python API has a similar command. I couldn't find one in Java though. http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/03_python.html